# Is it possible to control which layers are in front on deck.gl?

Tags: deck.gl

On Leaflet, when I create a layer from a GeoJSON, I have a way of controlling which layer is shown in front of the map by looping the layer features and then using a function like `feature.bringToFront()`. The result is like the following:

[image]

On deck.gl however, after creating my layers from a GeoJSON, it's hard to tell which layer is in front of the map... The following image is the same example made with deck.gl instead of Leaflet.

[image]

So, is there any way of controlling the feature that I want to show in front with deck.gl? I know I could change the elevation when the view of the map is from above, but in this case, it's not a good solution when I'm navigating through the 3D map. Is it possible to do on deck.gl? Can I force some specific feature to appear in front of others? Is there any parameter or function that controls that?

Answer (score 1):

Have been working on this for a few hours and from a leafletJs background.

The closest I've gotten to a `feature.bringToFront` equivalent is that you can order the layers and pass that to the DeckGl component, a description from the deck.gl documentation is here:

https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/using-layers#rendering-layers

The below works for me, however, it seems to work only for layers of the same type. In the example below, if I add a `LineLayer` type at index 0 of the layers array below, it will render in front of the two `SolidPolygonLayer`'s below.

```js
const layers = [
      new SolidPolygonLayer({
      id: 'at array index 0 and appears in the background',
      data: helper.getPolygonData(),
      getPolygon: d => d.coordinates,
      getFillColor: d => [255, 0, 0],
      filled: true,
    }),
    new SolidPolygonLayer({
      id: 'at array index 1 and appears in the foreground',
      data: helper.getPolygonData(),
      getPolygon: d => d.coordinates,
      getFillColor: d => d.color,
      filled: true,
    }),
  ];
  
  return (
    <DeckGL
      layers={layers}
      viewState={getViewState()}
      onViewStateChange={e => setViewState(e.viewState)}
      initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
      controller={true}
      getTooltip={getTooltip}
    >
    ...
    </DeckGL>
  );
```